# How to call and set arguments correctly for Keras fit generator

Tags: keras, neural-network

I'm new to Keras so I get confused between Keras documentation and other people's examples of using `fit_generator`. When I test-ran this code with 100 samples (for the sake of speedy output. The actual training sample is more than 10k) in batch size of 32 for 2 epochs:

```
# Create a generator that generates an image and a label one at a time (because loading all data into memory will freeze the laptop)

def generate_transform(imgs, lbls):
    while 1:       
        for i in range(len(imgs)):
            img = np.array(cv2.resize(imgs[i], (224, 224)))            
            lbl = to_categorical(lbls[i], num_classes=10)
            yield (img, lbl)  

history =  model.fit_generator(generate_transform(x[:100], y[:100]),
                                   steps_per_epoch=100/32,
                                   samples_per_epoch=100, 
                                   nb_epoch=2,
                                   validation_data=generate_transform(x_test[:100], y_test[:100]),
                                   validation_steps=100)
                                   # nb_val_samples=100?)
```

I got this UserWarning:

```
D:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:8: UserWarning: The semantics of the Keras 2 argument `steps_per_epoch` is not the same as the Keras 1 argument `samples_per_epoch`. `steps_per_epoch` is the number of batches to draw from the generator at each epoch. Basically steps_per_epoch = samples_per_epoch/batch_size. Similarly `nb_val_samples`->`validation_steps` and `val_samples`->`steps` arguments have changed. Update your method calls accordingly.

D:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:8: UserWarning: Update your `fit_generator` call to the Keras 2 API: `fit_generator(<generator..., steps_per_epoch=100, validation_data=<generator..., validation_steps=100, epochs=2)`
```

And the output looked like this:

```
Epoch 1/2
100/100 [==============================] - 84s 836ms/step - loss: 3.0745 - acc: 0.4500 - val_loss: 2.3886 - val_acc: 0.0300
Epoch 2/2
100/100 [==============================] - 86s 864ms/step - loss: 0.3654 - acc: 0.9000 - val_loss: 2.4644 - val_acc: 0.0900
```

My questions are:

1. Was my call correct with those arguments and their supplied values?
2. Was my model trained with 32 images and labels at each step; and it was trained with 100/32 steps per epoch?
3. Am I required to use the argument `steps_per_epoch`?
4. Which argument should I use: `validation_steps` or `nb_val_samples`?
5. Did my model validate all 100 samples of the validation generator (as indicated by `x_test[:100]`) for 100 times (as indicated by `validation_steps=100`) or it's only validating 100 times of one sample each (because validation generator only yield one sample at a time)? Why didn't the output show the number of steps?
6. Did my model use the trained weight from the first epoch to re-train the same data again, that's why the training accuracy jumped from 0.45 in the first epoch to 0.9 in the second epoch?

Could you please help me with the above questions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which keras version you are using?

Comment: Hi kruxx, I'm using Keras 2.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem & solved it in my code below {before in Keras 1.1.2 ==> after in Keras 2.2.4}:

```
294 # Old Keras==1.1.2 fit_generator
295 # history = model.fit_generator(
296 #    train_data_generator.get_data(),
297 #    samples_per_epoch=train_data_generator.get_num_files(),
298 #    nb_epoch=config["num_epochs"],
300 #    verbose=1,
301 #    validation_data=validation_data_generator.get_data(should_shuffle=False),
302 #    nb_val_samples=validation_data_generator.get_num_files(),
303 #    nb_worker=2,
304 #    max_q_size=batch_size,
305 #    pickle_safe=True)
306
307 # New working! Keras 2.2.4 fit_generator        
309 history = model.fit_generator(
310      train_data_generator.get_data(),
312      verbose=1,
313      validation_data=validation_data_generator.get_data(should_shuffle=False),
314      steps_per_epoch=train_data_generator.get_num_files() // batch_size,
315      epochs=config["num_epochs"],
316      validation_steps=validation_data_generator.get_num_files() // batch_size,
317      workers=2, use_multiprocessing=True,
318      max_queue_size=batch_size)
```

Looking at your code, you need just `steps_per_epoch` not `samples_per_epoch`, change `nb_epoch` to `epochs`. I don't fully understand your code or the training/validation setup (100 train & validation samples?) and it's best to ask one question per post, but I'll take a stab at fixing your code (untested of course):

Keep in mind that `number_of_steps == number_of_samples // batch_size` and if 100 is `num_training_samples`, you'll have to have a pretty small `batch_size` for `number_of_steps` to make sense:

```
history =  model.fit_generator(
    generate_transform(x[:100], y[:100]), # training data generator
    verbose=1,                  
    val_data=generate_transform(x_test[:100], y_test[:100]), # validation data generator
    steps_per_epoch=100 // batch_size, # 100 is num_training_samples, divided by batch_size == steps_per_epoch
    epochs=2,
    val_steps=100 // batch_size # 100 is num_val_samples, divided by batch_size == val_steps
    )
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm not sure why `batch_size` must be small to make sense? The reason I used batch size of 32 as it was Keras' default. Although you didn't address all my questions, but I think you had corrected my code, and I've learnt few new things from your `# New working! Keras 2.2.4 fit_generator`, I will accept your answer for now.

Comment: Thank you! An epoch usually means you've passed *all* your training data through the machine once. You will have multiple epochs until your accuracy converges (question 6). You can do 1 epoch in one batch (batch_size == num training samples) but most people divide all-training-data into mini-batches (of batch size == some division of all-training-data). You should study deeper how a batch of training data can be split for full/mini-batch training: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16807/why-mini-batch-size-is-better-than-one-single-batch-with-all-training-data

Comment: For validation, the validation examples are passed through the machine once (like a validation epoch (question 5)) but usually validation data is much smaller than training examples, so that part of your setup was a bit confusing to me. Here is a working example (with data) that you can step through, there are comments on exactly how the data is laid out, and you can try different things to break it, adapt your mental model: https://github.com/ruohoruotsi/LSTM-Music-Genre-Classification/blob/master/lstm_genre_classifier_keras.py

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I do understand about using full set or mini batches. I'm only unsure whether my model (as specified by the code in my question) trained a batch of 32 each step or not (because my fit_generator yields only one sample at a time). I was wondering whether the model's mechanism _waited_ for the generator produced 32 samples before it started to fit, then waited again for the next batch? I'd like to know what triggers the model to wait and start to fit; and how the generator knows to stop yielding the next sample.

Comment: Generally, processing (esp on GPUs) are vectorized, so a minibatch of inputs are loaded into memory (as a tensor aka multi-dim-array) and processed at once.  For the generator question, ask a new question or read up on generators https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly